# Best Practice for Multi-programming-language Projects

Tags: multilingual

Does anyone have any experience with doing this?  I'm working on a Java decompiler right now in C++, but would like a higher level language to do the actual transformations of the internal trees.  I'm curious if the overhead of marshaling data between languages is worth the benefit of a more expressive and language for better articulating what I'm trying to accomplish (like Haskell).  Is this actually done in the "real world", or is it usually pick a language at the beginning of a project and stick with it?  Any tips from those who have attempted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big advocate of always choosing the right programming language for each challenge. If there is another language which handles some otherwise tricky task easily, I'd say go for it.

Does it happen in the real world? Yes. I am currently working on a project which is made up of both PHP and objective-c code.

The trick is, as you pointed out, the communication between the two languages. If at all possible, let each language stick to its own domain, and have the two sections communicate in the simplest way possible. In my case, it was XML documents sent via http. In your case, some kind of formatted text file might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Marshalling costs depend on the languages and architecture you're working with. For example, if you're on the CLR or JVM, there are low-cost interop solutions available - though I know you are working with probably unmanaged C++.

Another avenue is an embedded domain-specific language. Tree transformations are often expressible via pattern matching and application of a relatively small number of functions. You could consider writing a simple tree pattern-matcher - e.g. something that looks like Lisp s-exprs but uses placeholders to capture variables - with associated actions that are functions that transform the matched subtree.

Comment: Definitely had considered the possibility of writing a domain-specific language.  I'll look into s-exprs, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[John Ousterhout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ousterhout%27s_dichotomy), the inventor of [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/) was a stong advocate of multi-language programming and wrote quite extensively about it.  In order to do it, you need a clean interface mechanism between the languages you are using for it.  There are quite a few mechanisms for this.  Examples of different mechanisms for doing this are:

- [SWIG (Simplified Wrapper and
  Interface Generator](http://www.swig.org/) can take a c
  or c++ (or several other languages)
  header file and generate an
  interface for a high level language
  such as perl or python that allows
  you to access the API.  There are
  other systems that use this
  approach.
- Java supports [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), and various
  other systems such as Python's
  [ctypes](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/), VisualWorks [DLL/C
  connect](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/documentation/current/COMConnectGuide.pdf) are native mechanisms
  that allow you to explicitly
  construct the call to the lower
  level subsystem.
- Tcl/Tk was designed explicitly to be
  embeded, and has a [native API](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11541)
  for a C library to add hooks into
  the language.  The constructs for
  this resemble argv[] structures in
  C, and were designed to make it
  relatively easy to interface a
  command-line based C program into
  Tcl.  This is similar to the above
  example, but coming from the opposite
  direction.  Many scripting languages
  such as Python, Lua and Tcl support
  this type of mechanism.
- Explicit glue mechanisms such as
  [Pyrex](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/Pyrex/), which are similar to a
  wrapper generator, but have their
  own language for defining the
  interface.  Pyrex is actually a
  complete programming language. 
  Middleware such as [COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctkast1b(VS.80).aspx) or
  [CORBA](http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/corbafaq.htm) allow a generic
  interface definition to be built
  externally to the application in an
  [interface definition language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367300(VS.85).aspx) 
  and language bindings for the
  languages concerned to use the
  common interface mechanism.